# MPV: Cycle through cover art (if multiple images are present) of the current playing flac file

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, metadata, flac, mpv

I have flac files that contains several embedded cover art which includes front, back, booklet etc. Is it possible to cycle through cover art (if multiple images are present) of the current playing flac file? Is there any shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon this while playing a .flac file by hitting `I` then `4` then scrolling down (use ) until I happen to notice the shortcut for cycling through video tracks, which is `_`

You can find this in the section for [keyboard control](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#keyboard-control) from the mpv manual

```
_     Cycle through the available video tracks.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).